# Kafka Consumer - Reset Consumer Poll time

Tags: timer, apache-kafka, reset, data-stream

I have a Kafka Consumer with poll time mentioned like

```
kafkaConsumer.poll(polltimeinmilliseconds);
```

I would like to update the poll timer dynamically. Right now I set that to a static variable , and the poll time updates.

The problem is , the consumer waits for the old timer to complete. i.e if the old timer was 5 minutes, and if I update the timer to 10 ( dynamimcally ), it duly waits for the first 5 minutes before updating to 10 minutes interval.

How do I reset it immediately. i.e the timer should reset and set to 10 minutes immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can abort a long poll using the [`wakeup`](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#wakeup--) method.

> Wakeup the consumer. This method is thread-safe and is useful in particular to abort a long poll. The thread which is blocking in an operation will throw WakeupException. If no thread is blocking in a method which can throw WakeupException, the next call to such a method will raise it instead.